# How to extract the last div?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

How can I extract the last div from these ones:

```
<div class="_1mil">
    <div class="_2yjq">Медсестра - Регистратор</div>
    <div class="pz-o"><span><span>требуемый опыт работы <span>от года до 3 лет</span></span></span></div> 
    <div>80 000 — 120 000 тг</div>
</div>
```

I need only the last one without a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `[-1]` to access the last element - in this case `<div>`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<div class="_1mil">
    <div class="_2yjq">Медсестра - Регистратор</div>
    <div class="pz-o"><span><span>требуемый опыт работы <span>от года до 3 лет</span></span></span></div> 
    <div>80 000 — 120 000 тг</div>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")


print(soup.select("._1mil div")[-1].text)
```

Prints:

```
80 000 — 120 000 тг
```

---

Or: Without `.select()`:

```
print(soup.find(class_="_1mil").find_all("div")[-1].text)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! The last `print(soup.find(class_="_1mil").find_all("div")[-1].text)`  helped ;)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would retrieve just the last item by doing the filtering with [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors). It's more compact and likely faster.

Here are two possibilities based on the html as shown:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html='''
<div class="_1mil">
    <div class="_2yjq">Медсестра - Регистратор</div>
    <div class="pz-o">
        <span>
            <span>требуемый опыт работы <span>от года до 3 лет</span></span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div>80 000 — 120 000 тг</div>
</div>

'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('._1mil div:last-child').text)
print(soup.select_one('._1mil div:last-of-type').text)
```